# windows 10 npm babel Please try running this command again as root/Administrator

Tags: cordova, npm, webpack, babeljs

[error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyAyi.png)

```
npm install --save-dev css-loader style-loader
```

Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

Comment: Did you try running it as Administrator?

Answer (score 1):

Try running it as Administrator:

1. Click start
2. type "cmd"
3. right click on "command line" and select run as administrator
4. run your command, i.e. `npm install --save-dev css-loader style-loader`